# Youtube_it gem: Query plus filter by published date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube, rubygems

I am using the Youtube_it gem to search via the [YouTube API](https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it).

I am trying to make a call which returns videos form either to day or a date range which match a query also.
For example, a query for videos about cats which were published today should look something like:

```
client.videos_by(:fields => {:published => (Date.today), :query => "cat"})
```

Shouldn't it?

I've tried a few different alternatives with no success thus far. Videos from today will be returned but the query parameter is ineffectual. Is this type of date filtered query possible via the gem? If so what format should it take?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the rdocs, :query should be outside the fields hash. Try:

```
client.videos_by(:query => "cat", :fields => {:published => (Date.today)})
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. No that doesn't work any better it return no results